# nvm with yarn Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed

Tags: yarnpkg, nvm

I have nvm:

```
nvm ls
        v8.11.3
        v8.11.4
->      v11.1.0
default -> 8.11.4 (-> v8.11.4)
node -> stable (-> v11.1.0) (default)
stable -> 11.1 (-> v11.1.0) (default)
```

I installed yarn with:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends yarn
```

I also added in .bashrc `alias node=nodejs`. But when I try `yarn install` I see:

```
Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/ankurk91/8f107ef490f40f74a1cf) helped on this problem.

Run the following commands

```
echo "==> Installing Yarn package manager"
rm -rf ~/.yarn
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
# Yarn configurations
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"
yarn config set prefix ~/.yarn -g
```

And add the following in `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

It should then work properly without the warning after restarting the shell.

Comment: ty for answer. I try to do this steps when i search in google my problem. The solution was simple: the problem was not in my development environment, but in the line of code that my partner added to webpack.config "preinstall": "sudo yarn global add prettifier eslint flow-bin" (he says it  needed on macOS, i use Ubuntu)

Comment: why does this problem happen? In one of my repo, it happens occasionally

Answer (score 6):

First uninstall the nodejs package:

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

Ubuntu 16.04 contains a version of Node.js in its default repositories that can be used to easily provide a consistent experience across multiple systems. At the time of writing, the version in the repositories is v4.2.6. This will not be the latest version, but it should be quite stable and sufficient for quick experimentation with the language.

In order to get this version, we just have to use the apt package manager. We should refresh our local package index first, and then install from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

If the package in the repositories suits your needs, this is all you need to do to get set up with Node.js. In most cases, you’ll also want to also install npm, which is the Node.js package manager. You can do this by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

This will allow you to easily install modules and packages to use with Node.js.

Because of a conflict with another package, the executable from the Ubuntu repositories is called nodejs instead of node. Keep this in mind as you are running software.

To check which version of Node.js you have installed after these initial steps, type:

```
nodejs -v
```

[Screenshot for nodejs version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JncjG.png)

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer help me somehow. But I would share the link of the nodejs versions from nodesource. https://github.com/nodesource/distributions. In your case you may want to download and install from https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention that my configuration file looked something like that

```
export PATH=$PATH:`yarn global bin`

#NVM INITIALIZATION STUFF
```

(yarn docs recommended $PATH)

the `export` was before my `nvm` initialization. Which meant node was not available during the runtime of that line. So I just switched my configuration file to be

```
#NVM INITIALIZATION STUFF

export PATH=$PATH:`yarn global bin`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. by putting nvm path above yarn path didn't solve the issue then I looked up for a solution in man page and solve the issue by setting default node version on a shell.

Current lts version is v14.17.6 so i install it use it and set default node version on a shell.

```sh
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
nvm alias default <version>
```

Additional you can set always default to the latest available node version on a shell by running below command.

```sh
nvm alias node <version>
```

Comment: in my case, forgot to `yarn build` before `yarn start`